# Make JSP accessible via RequestDispatcher#include only

Tags: jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

The problem I am trying to solve is that I have a web project running on Tomcat 7 with mostly publicly accessible JSP pages, but also with a few JSP pages that are not meant to be publicly accessible. These "private" pages are used by various servlets like so:

```
response.setContentType(...);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/private/example.jsp").include(request, response);
```

I want the private JSP pages to be accessible by `RequestDispatchaer#include()`, but *not* if a client navigates to e.g. */private/example.jsp* directly.

The way I am handling this now is I am setting a request attribute from the servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("okToAccess", true);
```

Then in the JSP page I check for that attribute, returning an empty document if it's not found. The two downsides to this are:

1. The code is boiler-platey and annoying to write.
2. Servlets dispatched via `include` can't modify response status/headers and so I can't e.g. send back a 403 or 404 from the JSP, I have to implement slightly more complex logic to let the calling servlet issue error responses instead.

My question is: Is there a cleaner way to block direct access to these "private" JSPs while still letting them be used with `include()`? Something I can put in `web.xml` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any content stored in WEB-INF won't be served directly by a web container. Place your private jsp files in that folder to force the request through a servlet.

Comment: how is it going to get compiled in the WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Amazing! I had no idea I could put arbitrary stuff in there.

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim I guess it works. I see people mentioning it [here](https://coderanch.com/t/291403/java/access-jsp-WEB-INF-folder#1332177). I didn't do enough digging to find an official spec.